# Named Schema in Google Cloud Spanner

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

By default, the tables I define in Google Spanner are stored in a default schema which is "unnamed" as explained in the [Information Schema document](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/information-schema).

What I need: I need my defined tables to have a named schema. Is there a way to create a named schema and have tables inside it?

What I did: I run `SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` and the result had two rows. One had `SCHEMA_NAME` as `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and the other was an empty string which is where my tables are defined.

I tried to update the `SCHEMA_NAME` column in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` table where the `SCHEMA_NAME` was an empty string but DML statements are not supported it seems.

Can someone give me a hint on how to make this work or if this is even possible? Thanks already!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work on Cloud Spanner at Google. Unfortunately named schemas are not supported by Cloud Spanner at this time.